# Configured Subdomain with nginx always gives warning

Tags: nginx, subdomain

I'm trying to configure a subdomain on my root server.
As I want to use this subdomain on port 80, I added another serverblock to the corresponding config file.

Everytime I start nginx now I get the following error:

```
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "domain.de" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
```

This is my config file:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain.de *.domain.de;
    rewrite ^(.*) http://domain.de$1 permanent;
}

server {
    listen 80;

    server_name domain.de;

    root /var/www_80;
[...]

}

server {
    listen   80; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied

    server_name cdn.domain.de;

    root /var/domain_streams;
[...]

}
```

If I visit my cdn.domain.de I get redirect to the correct site and the correct server part works, but I'm still getting this strange warning.

Can I just ignore it, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: remove the listen from each of the server blocks, you don't need them. you only need the listen once on the default server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `server_name domain.de` defined in two different `server` blocks. Since the intent of one of them is to redirect traffic to `domain.de`, having it there is clearly erroneous.

Comment: Okay, so I removed it for the first Server block, two of my error messages disappeared but two are still there ... thanks for the help!

Comment: Okay, my mistake. There was another line saying server_name which I totally did oversee for the last 4 hours... A couple 100 lines in one config is just too much.